# PyTorch: efficiently interleave two tensors in a custom order

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, torch

I want to create a new tensor `z` from two tensors, say `x` and `y` with dimensions `[N_samples, S, N_feats]` and `[N_samples, T, N_feats]` respectively. The aim is to combine both tensors on the 2nd dim by mixing the elements of the 2nd dim in a specific ordering, which is stored in a variable `order` with dim `[N_samples, U]`.

The ordering is different for every sample and is basically which index to extract from which tensor. It looks like this for a given sample `order[0]` - `[x_0, x_1, y_0, x_2, y_1, ... ]`, where the letter indicates the tensor and the number indicates the index of the 2nd dim. So `z[0]` would be

`z[0] = [x[0, 0, :], x[0, 1, :], y[0, 0, :], x[0, 2, :], y[0, 1, :] ... ]`

How would I achieve this? I've written something that uses `torch.gather` that tries to do this.

```
x = torch.rand((2, 4, 5))
y = torch.rand((2, 3, 5))

# new ordering of second dim
# positive means take (n-1)th element from x
# negative means take (n-1)th element from y
order = [[1, 2, -1, 3, -2, 4, 3], 
         [1, -1, -2, 2, 3, 4, -3]]

# simple concat for gather
combined = torch.cat([x, y], dim=1)

# add a zero padding on top of combined tensor to ease gather
zero = torch.zeros_like(x)[:, 1:2] 
combined = torch.cat([zero, combined], dim=1)

def _create_index_for_gather(index, offset, n_feats):
    new_index = [abs(i) + offset if i < 0 else i for i in index]

    # need to repeat index for each dim for torch.gather
    new_index = [[x] * n_feats for x in new_index]
    return new_index

_, offset, n_feats = x.shape
index_for_gather = [_create_index_for_gather(i, offset, n_feats) for i in order]

z = combined.gather(dim=1, index=torch.tensor(index_for_gather))
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?